# Plone 4.3 MailHost not mailing anymore

Tags: email, plone

I have a Plone 4.3 installation here, that stopped sending mails. More precisely: One of the installed sites, stopped mailing. The others work fine.

I did several tests with newly installed sites and everything worked as expected. I am sure, that the mail server listens on localhost and emails get processed by the host. I am also sure, that my configuration is OK, because it matches precisely with sites that do send mails.

I removed and reinstalled the MailHost in the sites root, but with no success. There is no trace of errors whatsoever in the error log, not even when I start a particular client in foreground mode.

I have no clue, how to debug this. My guess would be, to reinstall the underlying component in the portal_setup screen. But which I would need to reinstall?

Any other hints are very welcome.

Comment: Any traces in your SMTP agent's log? (Usually /var/log/mail.log, varies by system.)

Comment: No, no traces. This is kind of weird, because other sites and new sites of the same instance do mail... and the mails do arrive. I'll test the MailHost in a test view today.

Answer (score 1):

You could try temporarily raising the error log level from INFO to WARN or even DEBUG in zope.conf if you have not done so. This has helped me troubleshoot email sending problems in the past by providing SMTP error feedback that did not show up otherwise. My experience is in Plone 3 but I'm guessing this may still be the same or similar:

In `[project dir]/parts/[instance]/etc/zope.conf`

```
<eventlog>
    level WARN
    ...
</eventlog>
```

You have to restart the instance for this change to take effect.